# What to do about an outdated, but easily fixed, PKGBUILD in AUR?

Tags: arch-linux, packaging

I've found an outdated PKGBUILD on [AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/). The source URL that it references doesn't exist anymore. It can easily be fixed by incrementing a version number.

What is the proper way of solving this? I've already left a comment, but should I also flag the package as out-of-date? Should I send the fixed PKGBUILD somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track... from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR#Q%3a_Foo_in_AUR_is_outdated.3B_what_do_I_do.3F):

> For starters, you can flag packages out-of-date. If it stays
>   out-of-date for an extended period of time, the best thing to do is
>   email the maintainer. If there is no response from the maintainer
>   after two weeks, you could send mail to the [aur-general mailing list](https://www.archlinux.org/mailman/listinfo/aur-general)
>   to have a TU orphan the PKGBUILD if you're willing to maintain it
>   yourself.

Another option in the meantime, although this might not be a preferred practice... but, I have seen some users edit the PKGBUILD and then upload their version to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then link to it in the comments. Other users will still need to make manual edits but at least the update will be known.

Answer (score 1):

Besides leaving a comment (which will be seen by people downloading the PKGBUILD), flag it as out of date and try to contact the PKGBUILD's author.